# Как показать div при нажатии на чекбокс и спрятать div при снятии галочки с чекбокса?

Tags: javascript

Как показать div при нажатии на чекбокс и спрятать div при снятии галочки с чекбокса?
И чтобы при скрытии дива текст под ним подтягивался к чекбоксу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
function toggle() {
  var div = document.getElementById('pnlTest');
  if(this.checked)
    div.style.display = 'block';
  else
    div.style.display = 'none'
    }
document.getElementById('chkTest').onchange = toggle;
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest" />
<label for="chkTest">test</label>
<div id="pnlTest"></div>
<p>
  Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
```

Comment: чуть укоротить можно: function toggle() {document.getElementById('pnlTest').style.display = this.checked ? 'block' : 'none'}

Comment: А как можно сделать, чтобы див сначала был показанным (на чекбоксе по умолчанию галочка стоит, checked='checked'), а при снятии галочки, див пропадал?

Comment: можно вообще это через css сделать.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов: Удалите display: none из стилей, и div будет отображаться по умолчанию.

Comment: @eicto: [Можно](http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/dQcqn/), но для IE < 9 придется все-равно делать fallback.

Comment: А как добавить цикл этому делу, если есть несколько чекбоксов и несколько блоков, которые необходимо скрывать/показывать?